# Exactly-once semantics in Dataflow stateful processing

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are trying to cover the following scenario in a streaming setting:

- calculate an aggregate (let’s say a count) of user events since the start of the job
- The number of user events is unbounded (hence only using local state is not an option)

I'll discuss three options we are considering, where the two first options are prone to dataloss and the final one is unclear. We'd like to get more insight into this final one. Alternative approaches are of course welcome too.

Thanks!

---

### Approach 1: Session windows, datastore and Idempotency

1. Sliding windows of x seconds
2. Group by userid
3. update datastore

Update datastore would mean:

1. Start trx
2. datastore read for this user
3. Merging in new info
4. datastore write
5. End trx

The datastore entry contains an idempotency id that equals the sliding window timestamp

**Problem:**

Windows can be fired concurrently, and then can hence be processed out of order leading to dataloss (confirmed by Google)

### Approach: Session windows, datastore and state

1. Sliding windows of x seconds
2. Group by userid
3. update datastore

Update datastore would mean:

1. Pre-check: check if state for this key-window is `true`, if so we skip the following steps
2. Start trx
3. datastore read for this user
4. Merging in new info
5. datastore write
6. End trx
7. Store in state for this key-window that we processed it (`true`)

Re-execution will hence skip duplicate updates

**Problem:**

Failure between 5 and 7 will not write to local state, causing re-execution and potentially counting elements twice.
We can circumvent this by using multiple states, but then we could still drop data.

### Approach 3: Global window, timers and state

Based on the article [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html), we would create:

1. A global window
2. Group by userid
3. Buffer/count all incoming events in a stateful DoFn
4. Flush x time after the first event.

A flush would mean the same as Approach 1

**Problem:**

The guarantees for exactly-once processing and state are unclear. 
What would happen if an element was written in the state and a bundle would be re-executed? Is state restored to before that bundle?

Any links to documentation in this regard would be very much appreciated. E.g. how does fault-tolerance work with timers?

Answer (score 0):

From your Approach 1 and 2 it is unclear whether out-of-order merging is a concern or loss of data. I can think of the following.

Approach 1: Don't immediately merge the session window aggregates because of out of order problem. Instead, store them separately and after sufficient amount of time, you can merge the intermediate results in timestamp order.

Approach 2: Move the state into the transaction. This way, any temporary failure will not let the transaction complete and merge the data. Subsequent successful processing of the session window aggregates will not result in double counting.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! Your approach 1 suggestion would require an external data storage with an additional processing job that runs in batch, which would defeat the streaming purpose, no? Approach 2 uses a Datastore transaction, moving the state inside would result in writing state and then potentially failing the transaction, leading to a bad state and dropped data. Unless the state would be reset by reexecution?

Comment: Approach 1 - you are doing streaming for aggregating by session window and then a subsequent process to order them in sequence. How much out-of-order is expected? If it is very little, then the additional batching and processing won't be lagging much.  Approach 2 - yes, if there is a failure, it needs to be reprocessed. But if that's not desired (as it has its own challenges), then Approach 1 with storing the aggregates is the best. It separates the logic of aggregating and merging providing the desired resiliency.

Comment: Unclear how much out of order, it depends on the watermark lag of the pipeline as well I would say. Even the processing in sequence of those session windows is not guaranteed as we have come to notice. Could you elaborate on the approach two challenges? I think if state is restored this might in fact solve the problem..

Comment: If you have a problem only for one user in the stream, if you restore all the way back, you would end up processing the stream for other users as well which may already have been processed. You would need to compare the state and discard processing them. So choosing this approach can depend on how often you expect to encounter errors while merging the aggregate values.

Comment: That would indeed be necessary in approach 2 and is exactly what the state is for: to avoid duplicate processing. But the problem still remains: what if Dataflow fails after setting the state, then the result is stored in Datastore, but the old state is reset and we will do a new update. This would count them twice.

Comment: But if it's stored in the database, you know it's already processed. So, when it's reprocessed you can discard. But since the session windows are expected to come out of band, you can't just rely on a single state per user. You may need to have an array of states and discard the ones that are older than a certain time.

Comment: That is exactly the problem, we expect dataflow to solve this for us by providing certain guarantees or mechanisms to obtain exactly-once semantics. When we revert to managing state for different windows ourselves this makes the entire application more complex, which is exactly what we want to avoid by using a managed streaming service.