# Dataflow/Apache Beam: How can I access state from @FinishBundle?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Our pipeline buffers events and does an external fetch (for enrichment) every 500 events. When a timer is fired, these events are then processed when a **timer** fires. Of course, when you have e.g. 503 events, there will be 3 events that were not enriched.

From experiments we learned that `@FinishBundle` is always called before the timer.  It even seems the result of the bundle in **committed before the timer** executed (checkpointing?). If we could access the state from @FinishBundle and perform an enrichment on these last events, they would be part of the committed bundle.

I believe this would solve our **exactly-once** problem: currently the timer also needs to fetch and will do this again upon re-execution. When we could adjust the state in the `@FinishBundle` the fetch is no longer needed and when the timer re-executes it will start from the state.

Apparently, it is not possible to **access the state** from the `@FinishBundle` function, as the following gives errors:

```java
@FinishBundle
public void finishBundle(FinishBundleContext c,
                         @StateId("buffer") BagState<AwesomeEvent> bufferState) {
            LOG.info("--- FINISHBUNDLE CALLED ---");
            // TODO: ENRICHMENT
            LOG.info("--- FINISHBUNDLE DONE ---");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way of accessing the state from this function?

Also, am I making the correct assessment about the timer behavior?

Comment: I think that you can only use [`@StateId`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.StateId.html) in a `@ProcessElement` or `@OnTimer` method.

Comment: Exactly, but I really need to access it from the finish bundle in our case :)

Comment: Are you using approach 3 described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401303/exactly-once-semantics-in-dataflow-stateful-processing)? Kinda "hacky" but have you considered creating dummy events, that are not enriched/processed downstream, so that you constantly reach the 500 mark and there are no orphaned elements (no need to flush in `finishBundle`)?

Comment: why do you need that 500 event limit?  just for the sake of undertanding your issue better, would it solve your problem if no event limit at all?

Comment: @RuoyunHuang Thanks for your response! The 500 events are for batching the external calls. If I wouldn't do this, the timer code would need to do all the fetching. That means, in the face of re-execution due to failure, the fetch would happen again. Because the previous execution already (potentially) did a write, I would lose exactly-once execution semantics.

Comment: @GuillemXercavins Thanks for your response! I am indeed using an approach like Approach nr. 3 in the link. I don't yet see how the dummy elements could solve the problem of some events carrying over to the timer. Could you explain a bit further?